# What will be the ORA code if the Stored Procedure executes nothing?

Tags: oracle, plsql, exception

I have a Stored Procedures which I am calling from Java code. There is an IF block and that IF condition is false the procedure executes nothing. So what will be the ORA code in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ORA code will be `ORA-00000: normal successful completion` because no errors occurred.

If you want a different outcome you need to code something specific. What you do depends on the business rules you're enforcing. Perhaps you need to raise an exception? This example tests whether a parameter is populated and hurls an exception if it isn't:

```
if p_str is null then
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'parameter P_STR must be populated');
else
    ....
end if;
```

In this scenario the ORA code will be `ORA-20000`. Oracle reserves error numbers -20999 to -20000 for our own use.

---

> "what if update is running with no change in table"

Same thing. Anything which does not hurl an exception is a successful completion. In this case we can test whether an update changed anything with the `sql%rowcount` value:

```
update your_table
set whatever = p_str
where id = p_id; 
if sql%rowcount = 0 then
     raise_application_error(-20001, 'No rows in YOUR_TABLE match ID = '||p_id);
end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

The value returned by a call to SQLCODE (the "ORA code" you mention) is always going to be zero unless the function is called from within an exception handler.